# Terraform IAM binding for GCP Cloud Tasks

Tags: terraform-provider-gcp, google-iam

[Edited]

My concern is related with this [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/6599)

As I know there is no iam binding module in terraform for GCP CloudTasks.

The only solution is using module = terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google, where you can run gcloud commands within terraform.

That means in case that I want to assign viewer role to 3xSAs + 5xUsers + 2xGroups I should have 10 copies of my terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google module.

Similar with running 10 times bellow command:

```
gcloud tasks queues add-iam-policy-binding GCP_CLOUD_TASK_ID --member=serviceAccount:SERVICE_ACCOUNT --role=roles/cloudtasks.viewer
```

Suppose I have additional roles: cloudtasks.viewer, cloudtasks.enqueuer, cloudtasks.taskRunner etc., in result I get a lot of gcloud module copies in my .tf definition file.

Is there a workaround using tf loops, conditionals to simply de tf file definitions with gcloud module? Couldn't find any examples and can't figure it out by myself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Terraform supports creating and assigning IAM roles. Please edit your question to clarify what your problem is.